# Syntax for adding/removing font-lock keywords in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting, font-lock, cperl-mode

Most of what I do with Emacs is in perl, and for that `cperl-mode` is mostly excellent; the one major annoyance is that a simple `my $whatever` introduction is given the property `font-lock-keyword-face`, which nixes the advantage of having keywords **pop**.  I'm new to elisp, and so have been trying to play around with adding or removing keywords from `font-lock`.  While both [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontLockKeywords) and [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html) give the syntax, the regex is driving me crazy.  I got the following not to whine in my init:

`(font-lock-remove-keywords 'cperl-mode '(("\\<\\(my\\)")))`

And it does nothing.  The `\\<\\(my\\)` bit works in scratch with `re-builder` so I think I have a syntax issue here.  How do I add and remove keywords?

Comment: Fortunately comments can't receive demerits, so here goes:  You could define the offending keyword as your regular base font -- e.g., black foreground with white background.  I don't modify the source of Emacs itself, because I'm frequently building new versions from the Emacs Trunk.  What Lindydancer is suggesting makes since, but I haven't researched that before so I don't have a solution based thereon.

Comment: You may also want to take a look a the source `.../lisp/progmodes/cperl-mode.el` to see how the offending keyword is defined.  `my` is listed numerous times beginning at line 5129 of Emacs Trunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `font-lock-remove-keywords` function is designed to remove an existing font-lock rule, which, in font-lock jargon is a *font-lock keyword*.

If you apply it to something that is not an exact match of an existing font-lock rule, then it does nothing.

It is not designed to remove language keywords.

They best way to do this is to look at the variable `font-lock-keywords` and remove the rule that you don't like using `font-lock-remove-keywords` and then add a modified version of the rule using `font-lock-add-keywords`.

Comment: Do you mean `font-lock-remove-keywords` instead of `remove-font-lock-keywords`?

Comment: @xuhdev: Yes, of course I do -- I've updated the answer. (Gee -- I even wrote the **** function, once upon a time, and I can't even remember its name. I guess it's time to roll me into a nursing home...)